# Reducing a path in a CW-complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be a CW-complex with skeleta $X_0 \subset X_1 \subset \cdots $

Let $\gamma \colon [0,1] \rightarrow X$ be a path between points $x,y \in X_0$.

Because $[0,1]$ is compact, Im$\gamma \subset X_n$ for some $n > 0$.  (I think.)

I want to replace $\gamma$ with a path in $X_{n-1}$.  I would like to maybe take $\gamma' = \gamma \cap X_{n-1}$ and somehow "complete" it.

If I then continue this process, I will end up with a path in $X_1$.

How can I do this?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Which replacements $\gamma\mapsto\gamma'$ do you allow?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, any replacement guaranteeing $\gamma' \subset X_{n-1}$ and $\gamma'(0) = x$, $\gamma'(1) = y$.  Of course $\gamma '$ will also have to be a path.

Comment: Do you want $\gamma'$ to be homotopic to $\gamma$?

Comment: Not necessarily!  But if we can find one that is, it would be quite nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\gamma$ is in fact homotopic, rel endpoints, to a path in the 1-skeleton. As you say, it certainly lies in the $n$-skeleton for some $n$. By a general position argument, if $n > 1$, you can alter $\gamma$ by a small perturbation so that it misses the center of each $n$-cell. Let's let $X^n$ denote $X_n$ without the centers of the $n$-cells. Then $X^n$ deformation retracts onto $X_{n-1}$ in general, just as a punctured disk retracts onto its boundary. By composing $\gamma$ with such a deformation, we homotop it into a path in $X_{n-1}$. Do this repeatedly until you get to $n = 1$, at which point the general-position argument fails, but that's OK, because you've got what you wanted.